# Is there any modified version of Djikstra with O(V+E) complexity?

Tags: time-complexity, dijkstra

I am looking to create a modified version of Djikstra to find number of shortest paths from a source to a target vertex. Using arrays, I have O(V^2), using binary heap, I have O(ElgV), and using Fibonacci heap, I have O(E+VlgV).
Is there a way to modify it to be O(V+E) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the graph is acyclic (DAG) it is possible to use topological sorting to achieve O(V+E).